# How to copy one BLOB to another without losing special chars?

Tags: oracle, triggers, blob

I can't insert a blob that comes from a trigger (:NEW.BLOB_COL) into a table that has a blob column without data "corruption".

I can read the blob in :NEW (not corrupted) as "`ëïüÿëïüÿëüÿ`", but after I read it after it's been inserted in my table it's "`&euml;&iuml;&uuml;&yuml;&euml;&iuml;&uuml;&yuml;&euml;&uuml;&yuml;`".

Can someone tell me how to save it correctly?

EDIT:
insert into table_name (x_blob) values (:new.y_blob)

how come that wasn't clear

EDIT2:

Can't paste the exact sql export (for corporate reasons)

```
CREATE TABLE "XXX_IT5050"."BR_NOTE"   (
    ....
    "BR_HTML_NOTE" BLOB,
    ....   )

CREATE TABLE "YYY_IT5050"."EVENT"   (
    ....
    "EVENT_DESC" BLOB,
    ....   )
```

Comment: how are you reading it?

Comment: Looks like you actually have a `CLOB` column not a `BLOB` column. What is the `CREATE TABLE` for the tables involved?